# PHP Passing Arguments On Executing Shell Command

Tags: php, shell

I have a form with number and message textbox. Upon form submit I am running an executable file which is for sending text message. I want to get the user input which is the number and message along with the exe file.

and here is my code with my form:

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit']){
    $to = $_POST['to'];
    $msg = $_POST['message'];
    exec('START C:\SMS\abc.exe -Compose $to $msg');
    echo "Message Sent";
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?>" method="POST">
    <label class="control-label">To:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="to">
    <textarea class="inbox-editor form-control" name="message" rows="12"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btn blue" value="Send" id="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

It reads the "$to" and "$message" not the value of the textbox input.

Comment: Time for some basics: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: Could you give the sample syntax in command line?

Comment: instead of `exec`, try typing `die`. It will not send the message, but output the string. That'll allow you to see the actual command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```
$output = shell_exec('START C:\SMSCaster\smscaster.exe -Compose ' . $to . ' "' . $msg . '" -Queue 1');
```

Comment: Hello sir @Dolly, I transferred my codes on server computer then when i tried running the codes with this same codes it won't start/run the exe file but on command prompt it is working. sorry for this follow up question sir.

Comment: usually the problem on concatenation string. Please watch the single quote `'` , dit `.` and `"` double quotes usage

Comment: The string is not the error sir. I think its because apache is running on services. but i don't know how to fix it. it tried changing automatic start up to manual.